# Is there a way to create a linked server from an Azure SQL database to PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, azure, linked-server

I have been doing some research and I am yet to see a solution regarding this question. Does anyone know if it's actually possible to create a linked server from an Azure SQL database in order to connect it to a PostgreSQL database?

I noticed the folder `server objects` is present in the local database, however, on Azure that folder is non-existent. Am I right to assume linked server is not supported on the Azure SQL database?

Comment: Appears to be supported only in Azure SQL Managed Instances - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I know this was long time ago, but I am trying to connect to PostgreSQL db in Azure from   Azure SQL DB, but I cannot execute the CREATE EXTERNAL DATASOURCE command because the connection_options parameter is not available. Did you get this to work somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right.

Azure SQL database(single database) doesn't support [linked server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).  We can not create the linked server to any other Server.

[image]

I found an another way may can help you connect to Postgresql.

Please reference this tutorial: [Connect to PostgreSQL as an External Data Source using PolyBase](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/postgresql-odbc-polybase.rst):

Use the CData ODBC Driver for PostgreSQL and PolyBase to [create an external data source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in SQL Server 2019 with access to live PostgreSQL data.

**Creating a Master Encryption Key**

Execute the following SQL command to create a new master key, 'ENCRYPTION,' to encrypt the credentials for the external data source.

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password';
```

**Creating a Credential Database**

Execute the following SQL command to create credentials for the external data source connected to PostgreSQL data.

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL postgresql_creds
WITH IDENTITY = 'username', SECRET = 'password';
```

**Create an External Data Source for PostgreSQL**

Execute the following SQL command to create an external data source for PostgreSQL with PolyBase, using the DSN and credentials configured earlier.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE cdata_postgresql_source
WITH ( 
  LOCATION = 'odbc://SERVERNAME[:PORT]',
  CONNECTION_OPTIONS = 'DSN=CData PostgreSQL Sys',
  -- PUSHDOWN = ON | OFF,
  CREDENTIAL = postgresql_creds
);
```

**Create External Tables for PostgreSQL**

The statement to create an external table based on a PostgreSQL Orders would look similar to the following:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Orders(
  ShipName [nvarchar](255) NULL,
  ShipCity [nvarchar](255) NULL,
  ...
) WITH ( 
  LOCATION='Orders',
  DATA_SOURCE=cdata_postgresql_source
);
```

I couldn't test this for you because I don't have PostgreSQL.

Hope this helps.